# how to integrate ASIHTTPRequest to iphone project

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
 I am trying to add ASIHTTPRequest library to my iphone project
```

i followed these lines

```
Integrating ASIHTTPRequest

ASIHTTPRequest is a powerful open source library written by Ben Copsey from All-Seeing Interactive (and he’s a fellow cocos2d developer too!) It makes it easy to post data and files, and has tons of other great features too like cache support, easy access to HTTP headers, cookie support, and much more.

So let’s add ASIHTTPRequest to our project. Take the following steps:

   1. Download the latest version of ASIHTTPRequest.
   2. Back in FBFun, right click FBFun under “Groups & Files”, click “Add\New Group”, and name the group “ASIHTTPRequest”.
   3. Drag all of the files from the “pokeb-asi-http-request-xxx\Classes” to your new group. Make sure “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)” is checked, and click “Add”.
   4. Repeat the above for the 2 files in “pokeb-asi-http-request-xxx\External\Reachability”.
   5. Right click the Frameworks folder, and click “Add\Exisitng Frameworks…”. Choose CFNetwork from the list, and click Add.
   6. Repeat the above for SystemConfiguration.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, CoreGraphics.framework and libz.1.2.3.dylib (at the bottom of the list).
   7. Compile your project. If it works, you’re integrated!

We’ll explain about how ASIHTTPRequest works when we start to use it. But first, let’s integrate the JSON Framework while we’re at it.
```

but it not worked for me .while building it showing errors

```
/Classes/Tests/GHUnitTestMain.m:32:26: error: GHUnit/GHUnit.h: No such file or directory
```

can anybody help me in this issue

Regards

Thanks

****Edit : 
I fixed my problem by following these steps 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions ,
If any one want to integrate ASIHTTPRequest just follow those steps :)****

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the XML library (it's missing in the instructions), and also make reference to it in the project header search paths with the following:

$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2